# Render dynamic html in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use html instead of jsx code.
Various issues regarding this are:

1)How to take my html out of the component file and put it in the other file and then import that file in to my component file ..

2) We are using the proxy server to externalize the html template in current angular project. I want to achieve the same result with react.

3) Is there any way to separate out the JSX code in template so that i can be externalize using some proxy being a http resource.

Comment: What is your use case? You can render dynamic content with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but then you might as well use JSX.

Comment: The best route to take would be breaking out your jsx into a reusable generic stateless react component , that way it could be used in other components . Next I would recommend you take a look into server side rendering react which would allow you to request component templates from a server... here's a link
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e